# Is the content of a padding deterministic?

Tags: c++, casting, memory-alignment

On many architectures where char takes 1 byte and int 4 bytes, this would results in 6 instead of 5 bytes :

```
struct test {

char a;
int b;
};
```

Are the values of the padded bits well defined ? I need to know this because I want to cast (reinterpret) test instances into string instances's data (I will take of updating the size as well) such as two equal instances (having same value for a and b) of test would compare equal when testing the resulting string instances.

Comment: I would'nt bet on this as the philosophy of C(++) has always been to favor efficient constructs at the expense of portability.

Comment: that would result in 8 bytes, not 6

Comment: The values of the padding "bits" is not defined.   What's wrong with the expression `instance1.a == instance2.a && instance1.b == instance2.b` for determining if two instances are equal?

Comment: @Peter : In fact, my problem is that I need a hashtable whose key are of type test, so I am required to provide a hash function, so I thought about converting a test into a string and hashing the string... (I know there are other ways such as hashing test::a and test::b separately and XORIng but I keep hearing that they are not recommended)

Comment: @BЈовић The size of `test` depends on the implementation.

Comment: @user2370139 If you try to read padding bits, you are essentially reading uninitialized values. This is undefined behavior.